# Check / remove proxies from iPhone USB Personal Hotspot

Tags: network, proxy, tethering

I installed Charles Proxy to do some testing, later I disocvered that any traffic going through Personal Hotspot is also routed though to a local port. I've remove the Mac OS X proxy settings, but unless I have Charles open, I cannot connect over HTTP.

I have checked System Preferences > Network and there's no trace of any proxy settings. Can I use any command line tools to list and remove proxies?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but for anyone else that hits this problem:

Within Terminal.app issue the command:

```
networksetup  -setwebproxystate iPhone\ USB off
```

Afterwards, you can check that is disabled by using:

```
networksetup -getwebproxy iPhone\ USB
```

This should return `Enabled: No Server: 127.0.0.1 Port: 8888`

Comment: Can then check that is disabled by using `$ networksetup  -getwebproxy iPhone\ USB `  Should result in 
`Enabled: No
Server: 127.0.0.1
Port: 8888
`

Comment: Thanks, this saved me! You may want to add networksetup  -setsocksfirewallproxystate iPhone\ USB off which will also disable a SOCKS proxy if it's setup